# When I suggest that a question be migrated why does it only give me two choices?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migration

this question https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/16938/hdmi-connecting-shield-with-ground would get a better answer on [Electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) but when I vote to close and choose the `This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network` radio button, the only options I get are Meta and Audio Production:

[image]

Could we get a few more SE sites in the list of other sites? At least Electronics, SuperUser and maybe SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While we are in beta, the only way to get a migration to another site is to flag for moderator attention and get us to migrate them.

Once this site graduates, we choose our list of migration destinations from the ones most commonly migrated to.